# OpenMP implementation slowed down by Lapack's DSYSV

Tags: python, openmp, cython, lapack, blas

I have written an algorithm in Cython that frequently executes Lapack and Blas routines. As the individual calls to these routines are independent of each other, I attempted to speed things up by parallelizing the computation using OpenMP. Unfortunately, the use of multiple threads results in a significant slowdown compared to the single-threaded version and it is not clear to me what is happening.

## Minimal working example

I have created a minimal working example for you to reproduce the problem.

In the file `main.py` some dummy data is created and the algorithm, which is implemented in the Cython function `run_test`, is started:

```
import numpy as np
import cProfile
from test import run_test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_ordinates = 500
    np.random.seed(1)
    m = np.ascontiguousarray(np.where(np.random.randint(2, size=(num_ordinates,)) > 0, 1, -1), dtype=float)
    ordinates = np.zeros(num_ordinates, dtype=float, order='C')
    num_coefficients = (num_ordinates * (num_ordinates + 1) // 2)
    coefficients = np.zeros(num_coefficients, dtype=float, order='C')
    k = 0

    for i in range(num_ordinates):
        v = m[i]
        ordinates[i] += v / (num_ordinates + 1)

        for j in range(i):
            coefficients[k] -= -m[j] * v / pow(num_ordinates + 1, 2)
            k += 1

        coefficients[k] += abs(v) * num_ordinates / pow(num_ordinates + 1, 2)
        k += 1

    num_threads = 8
    cProfile.run('run_test(coefficients, ordinates, num_threads)')
```

The algorithm is implemented in a file called `test.pyx`. It performs several iterations of the same computations on the given data. In each iteration Lapack's DSYSV routine, as well as Blas' DDOT and DSPMV routines are called. The outer loop uses the `prange` command to be able to distribute the iterations across a specified number of threads.

```
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from scipy.linalg.cython_lapack cimport dsysv
from scipy.linalg.cython_blas cimport ddot, dspmv
from cython.parallel cimport prange

cpdef double run_test(double[::1] coefficients, double[::1] ordinates, int num_threads):
    cdef double *coefficients_ptr = &coefficients[0]
    cdef double *ordinates_ptr = &ordinates[0]
    cdef int n = ordinates.shape[0]
    cdef double result = 0
    cdef double *out
    cdef double *out2
    cdef double tmp
    cdef int i

    for i in prange(1000, nogil=True, num_threads=num_threads):
        out = run_dsysv2(coefficients_ptr, ordinates_ptr, n)
        tmp = run_ddot(out, ordinates_ptr, n)
        out2 = run_dspmv(coefficients_ptr, out, n)
        result += run_ddot(out, out2, n)
        free(out)
        free(out2)

    return result

cdef double* run_dsysv(double *coefficients, double *ordinates, int n) nogil except +:
    cdef double *a = <double*>malloc(n * n * sizeof(double))
    cdef double *b = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
    cdef int i, j, offset
    cdef int k = 0

    for i in range(n):
        b[i] = ordinates[i]
        offset = i * n

        for j in range(i + 1):
            a[offset + j] = coefficients[k]
            k += 1

    cdef char* uplo = 'U'
    cdef int nrhs = 1
    cdef int info
    cdef double worksize
    cdef int lwork = -1
    dsysv(uplo, &n, &nrhs, a, &n, <int*>0, b, &n, &worksize, &lwork, &info)
    lwork = <int>worksize
    cdef double *work = <double*>malloc(lwork * sizeof(double))
    cdef int *ipiv = <int*>malloc(n * sizeof(int))
    dsysv(uplo, &n, &nrhs, a, &n, ipiv, b, &n, work, &lwork, &info)

    free(ipiv)
    free(work)
    free(a)

    if info != 0:
        with gil:
            raise ArithmeticError('Non-zero info code: ' + str(info))

    return b

cdef double run_ddot(double *x, double *y, int n) nogil:
    cdef int inc = 1
    return ddot(&n, x, &inc, y, &inc)

cdef double* run_dspmv(double* m, double* a, int n) nogil:
    cdef char* uplo = 'U'
    cdef double alpha = 1
    cdef int inc = 1
    cdef double beta = 0
    cdef double *out = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
    dspmv(uplo, &n, &alpha, m, a, &inc, &beta, out, &inc)
    return out
```

For completeness, here is also the `setup.py` file:

```
import numpy
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from setuptools import setup, Extension

extensions = [
    Extension(name='*', sources=['*.pyx'], language='c++', extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
              extra_link_args=['-fopenmp'], define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")])
]

compiler_directives = {
    'boundscheck': False,
    'wraparound': False,
    'cdivision': True,
    'initializedcheck': False
}

setup(name='test',
      packages=['test'],
      install_requires=[
          "numpy>=1.19.0",
          "scipy>=1.5.0",
          "Cython>=0.29.0"
      ],
      python_requires='>=3.7',
      ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level='3', compiler_directives=compiler_directives),
      include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()])
```

I compile the program using the command `python3.7 setup.py build_ext --inplace`.

## Profiling

I ran a single-threaded and a multi-threaded variant of the code on my system by setting the variable `num_threads` in `main.py` to `1` and `8`, respectively. I obtained the following runtimes:

```
num_threads=1: 5.614 seconds
num_threads=8: 50.541 seconds
```

As you can see, the multi-threaded variant is about ten times slower and it is not clear to me why this is happening.

Here are my system's specifications:

```
OS: (Arch) Linux
16GB RAM
Intel Core i7-4710MQ CPU (8 cores @ 2.50GHz)
```

I guess it would also be helpful to know which versions of Blas and Lapack are being used. I am using the versions packaged with scipy 1.5.2, but I am not aware of the exact version numbers. I would appreciate any tips about how to get to know them.

## Some additional testing

I assumed that maybe the problem arises because too much memory is allocated before running the DSYSV routine, causing some other data to be pushed out of some CPU cache. To investigate this, I tried to remove the call to the DSYSV routine from the function `run_dsysv` in `test.pyx`. I replaced the original function with the following, where I tried to stay as close as possible to the original code (in particular, I wanted to keep the memory allocations):

```
cdef double* run_dsysv(double *coefficients, double *ordinates, int n) nogil except +:
    cdef double *a = <double*>malloc(n * n * sizeof(double))
    cdef double *b = <double*>malloc(n * sizeof(double))
    cdef int i, j, offset
    cdef int k = 0

    for i in range(n):
        b[i] = ordinates[i]
        offset = i * n

        for j in range(i + 1):
            a[offset + j] = coefficients[k]
            k += 1

    cdef char* uplo = 'U'
    cdef int nrhs = 1
    cdef int info
    cdef double worksize
    cdef int lwork = -1
    dsysv(uplo, &n, &nrhs, a, &n, <int*>0, b, &n, &worksize, &lwork, &info)
    lwork = <int>worksize
    cdef double *work = <double*>malloc(lwork * sizeof(double))
    cdef int *ipiv = <int*>malloc(n * sizeof(int))

    # dsysv(uplo, &n, &nrhs, a, &n, ipiv, b, &n, work, &lwork, &info)
    cdef double v

    for i in range(n):
        k = (((i + 1) * (i + 2)) // 2) - 1
        v = coefficients[k]
        v = -ordinates[i] / v if v != 0 else 0
        b[i] = v

    free(ipiv)
    free(work)
    free(a)

    return b
```

Running the single- and multi-threaded version of the updated code results in the following:

```
num_threads=1: 0.160 seconds
num_threads=8: 0.089 seconds
```

The program is of course much faster than before, because the computationally demanding DSYSV routine has been replaced with some code that runs in linear time. Nevertheless, we can see that the use of multiple threads now results indeed in a speed up compared to the single-threaded version. At least it does not result in a significant slowdown. Hence, I assume that the problem has something to do with the DSYSV routine, but not necessarily with the memory allocated for it.

Comment: DSYSV  is already parallelized (it should be) and there is no gain in running multiple DSYSV in parallel as all CPUs are already utilized. Even more, different DSYSVs hinder eachother (invalidating cache and so on) and it becomes slower.

Comment: Is it possible to turn off the internal parallelization of DSYSV? If possible, will different DSYSVs still hinder each other?

Comment: I checked the system monitor when running with `num_threads=1` (should have done that before) and indeed it seems like all cores are being used by DSYSV.

Comment: Switching off parallelisation of LAPACK routines depends heavily on the implementation used.